# Get POST request headers after click() and wait() in Nightmare JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I'm crawling a page where I `type()` something in an input field, `click()` a button and then `wait()` for some element to appear.

I would like to get all the headers for the POST request that is fired after `click()`.

I see that [`goto()`](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#gotourl-headers) returns the headers, but I don't think I can use it in my case because after `click()` I stay on the same page.

Here is an example of my code on another test page (I would like to get the POST request headers after `wait()`):

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });

nightmare
    .goto('https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/300/')
    .click('tbody tr:nth-child(5) td form input[type=submit]')
    .wait('body p:nth-of-type(3)')
    .evaluate(function () {
        return document.querySelector('body p:nth-of-type(3)').innerText;
    })
    .end()
    .then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.error('Search failed:', error);
    });
```

Note: I use Nightmare 2.10.0 and Node.js 8.1.3.

Answer (score 1):

There's no simple way of doing this that I'm aware of.

You can, however, get that information.

## Via `.on('did-get-response-details', callback)`

If you call `.on('did-get-response-details')` its callback will have the following information:

- `event` `Event`
- `status` `Boolean`
- `newURL` `String`
- `originalURL` `String`
- `httpResponseCode` `Integer`
- `requestMethod` `String`
- `referrer` `String`
- `headers` `Object`
- `resourceType` `String`

You have to call `.on(<event>)` prior to calling `.goto()`.

A list of available events is located here: https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/web-contents/#instance-events

## Via `.evaluate`

You could go directly to the POST endpoint via ajax (instead of submitting the form via a form submission).

Ajax example stolen from here: [Send POST data using XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest)

```
nightmare.evaluate(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "get_data.php";
        var params = "lorem=ipsum&name=binny";
        http.open("POST", url, true);
        
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        
        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                resolve(http); // <- Get some data here
            }
        }
        http.send(params);
    });
});
```

How these two ideas would specifically address your use case would depend on some things.